# NHibernate.Bytecode.UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have the following code set up in my Startup

```
IDictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

properties.Add("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver");
properties.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect");
properties.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle");
properties.Add("connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
properties.Add("connection.connection_string", "Data Source=ZEUS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxxx");
InPlaceConfigurationSource source = new InPlaceConfigurationSource();
source.Add(typeof(ActiveRecordBase), (IDictionary<string, string>) properties);

Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("Repository");

Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(asm, source);
```

I am getting the following error:

`failed: NHibernate.Bytecode.UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException : Unable to load type 'NNHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle' during configuration of proxy factory class.`

Possible causes are:

- The NHibernate.Bytecode provider assembly was not deployed.
- The typeName used to initialize the 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory section is not well formed.

I have read and read I am referecning the All the assemblies [listed](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/gettingstarted/ar.html) and I am at a total loss as what to try next.

Castle.ActiveRecord.dll
Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll
Iesi.Collections.dll
log4net.dll
NHibernate.dll
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll
Castle.Core.dll.

I am 100% sure the assembly is in the bin. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this all being done within the scope of a single project, or does your solution have multiple projects?

Comment: multiple and I do have the Castle.Core.dll it was just missing off the list

Comment: you misspelled NNHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory (two N instead of one)

Comment: Just a cut and copy error, I have made an edit to fix it now

Comment: are you sure the dependencies versions match? are all the DLLs from the ActiveRecord release ZIP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem occurs when NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll was built with a different target platform as your project. To test this, change your program target platform from one or more of the following:

- x64 to x86
- x86 to x64
- "Any CPU" to x86
- "Any CPU" to x64

If any of those solve your problem, then you know that you just need to synchronize the DLL and your target platform.

Comment: Yes. I had the same issue and actually gave up and stopped using the Castle DLL. Later on, I figured out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, my solution was to add in the Assembly that creates session following code.

```
private NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory requiredButNeverUsed;
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You didn't reference Castle assemblies and they weren't copied over to your output directory.