# NHibernate UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, window

I have a similar problem to the one posted
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481586/nhibernate-bytecode-unabletoloadproxyfactoryfactoryexception).

**Here's my code (c#):**

```
var nHConfig = new Configuration().Configure();
var sessionFactory = nHConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
```

The actual configuration is detailed in an `App.config` file:

```
<session-factory>
  ...
  <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
    NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
  </property>
  ...
</session-factory>
```

I am referencing both `NHibernate.dll` and `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll`.

**Here's the error I get:**

> failed: NHibernate.Bytecode.UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException : Unable to load type 'NNHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle' during configuration of proxy factory class.

**Here is the solution accepted in the** [aforementioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481586/nhibernate-bytecode-unabletoloadproxyfactoryfactoryexception) (answer given by [Kevin Crowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81193/kevin-crowell)):

> *This problem occurs when NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll was built with a different target platform as your project. To test this, change your program target platform from one or more of the following:*
>
> - *x64 to x86*
> - *x86 to x64*
> - *"Any CPU" to x86*
> - *"Any CPU" to x64*
>
> *If any of those solve your problem, then you know that you just need to synchronize the DLL and your target platform.*

**My problem is this -**

When I try running the application after changing the target platform, Visual Studio raises the following error:

> Error while trying to run project. Cannot start debugging. The assembly to be debugged was built with a platform incompatible with the current system.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong, and what I can do to correct or work around the problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Referencing `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll` from your project is not necessary since it is a dependency resolved runtime. You must ensure that the assebly is present in the private bin path of your application ( near the executable for a desktop app, in the /bin path for a web application ) and that the other dependencies of that assembly are present too.
As an additional reference, from version 3.2.0 GA there is a default proxy factory pointing to an internal LinFu proxy, see this JIRA:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2586
so if you have any special needing to use the castle proxies, yoo can completely avoid the configuration of the proxy factory.